# DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack://frontend/node_modules/react-router

Tags: webpack, devtools

Tried to use Django and react to create a website. webpack could not load react-router, react-router-dom, and @remix-run from node-module. How could I solve this bug?

Warning message:
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack://frontend/node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.js.map: Fetch through target failed: Unsupported URL scheme; Fallback: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

I am stuck and do not know what to do.